# Cannot find resources folder in xcode 4 (For Default.png)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, default.png

I have a navigation based app in xcode 4. I am trying to add the required launch image (Default.png), which as per instructions has to be added to the "resources" folder. I cannot find said folder. There is a "Supporting files" folder.

How do I add Default.png/launch image in xcode 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click you project and select targets. In the tab for summary you can configure all the icons.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen. My field doesn't have Landscape (since I did not set it up to have it).. It has "retina display" can I use the same image or does retina have different requirements? Thanks

Comment: If you dont have a retina display image then you can leave it blank. Or you have to give a image whose resolution is twice your normal image.

Comment: So it won't cause any issues with apple when submitting the app, correct?

Comment: Nope, submitting retina display images is optional. But it sure makes your app look great.